# Cannot download_file from S3 to lambda after notification that S3 object was created

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have configured SES to put some emails into S3 bucket and set a S3 trigger to fire lambda function on object created. In lambda, I need to parse and process the email. Here is my lambda (relevant part):

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(‘xxxxxxxx')
    my_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    filename = '/tmp/'+ my_key
    logger.info('Target file: ' + filename)
    s3client.download_file(my_bucket, my_key, filename)
#   Process email file
```

download_file throws an exception:

```
expected string or bytes-like object: TypeError


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 22, in lambda_handler
s3client.download_file(my_bucket, my_key, filename)

...

File "/var/runtime/botocore/handlers.py", line 217, in validate_bucket_name
if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Any idea what is wrong? The bucket is fine, object exists in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to the bucket name (and you have a strange curly quote in your code).

The [recommended](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html) way to retrieve the object details is:

```
for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']
    ...
    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
```

Comment: Curly quote is an artifact of masking the bucket name in my code snippet. This is not a reason. I will edit the question.

Comment: Ah! @Maurice found the answer. As per this sample code, the bucket name needs to be a string, not an object. The error message was perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: My first answer was probably wrong, here's another attempt**

The validation function that throws the exception can be found [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1.12.71/botocore/handlers.py)

```
# From the S3 docs:
# The rules for bucket names in the US Standard region allow bucket names
# to be as long as 255 characters, and bucket names can contain any
# combination of uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers, periods
# (.), hyphens (-), and underscores (_).
VALID_BUCKET = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$')

# [I excluded unrelated code here]

def validate_bucket_name(params, **kwargs):
    if 'Bucket' not in params:
        return
    bucket = params['Bucket']
    if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
        error_msg = (
            'Invalid bucket name "%s": Bucket name must match '
            'the regex "%s"' % (bucket, VALID_BUCKET.pattern))
        raise ParamValidationError(report=error_msg)
```

boto3 uses the S3Transfer Download Manager under the hood, which then uses the `download` method that is defined as [follows](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/manager.py):

```
def download(self, bucket, key, fileobj, extra_args=None,
             subscribers=None):
    """Downloads a file from S3
    :type bucket: str
    :param bucket: The name of the bucket to download from
...
```

It expects the `bucket` parameter to be a string and you're passing an `s3.Bucket(‘xxxxxxxx')` object, which probably isn't a string.

**I'd try to pass the bucket name to `download_file` as a string.**

---

**Old and most likely wrong answer as pointed out in the comments**

Some [sample code in the Boto Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html) shows us how downloads from S3 can be performed:

```
import boto3
import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'my_image_in_s3.jpg' # replace with your object key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'my_local_image.jpg')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

Looking at your code, it seems as if you're calling the `download_file` method the wrong way, it should look like this - you need to call the method on the Bucket-Object:

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(‘xxxxxxxx')
    my_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    filename = '/tmp/'+ my_key
    logger.info('Target file: ' + filename)
    my_bucket.download_file(my_key, filename)
#   Process email file
```

The important part is `my_bucket.download_file(my_key, filename)`

Comment: There are two ways of using boto: The client method (as shown in the question) or the resource method (as shown in your answer). Both are perfectly valid.

Comment: I did some further investigation into the code of boto3 and apparently it expects the bucketname to be a string instead of  an object like this: `s3.Bucket(‘xxxxxxxx')` - added that as an answer.

Comment: If using the client method, then it takes a string: `s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)`. If using the resource method, the the method runs on the bucket object: `s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'my_local_image.jpg')`